# How to get Remaining Maturity Date One Year or Less

Tags: sql-server

Need help writing
Remaining maturity of one year or less

Columns

```
Identiity_Code
ID_Number
GL_Account_ID
As_Of_Date
Cur_Book_Bal
Maturity_Date
```

My as_of_date is 12/31/2017

Using sql dev.
Working with time deposits(cd's)Need to pull anything that will have a year or less remaining maturity showing current book balance of less than 250000. The as of date is the quarter date of records I have to pull as well.

Comment: `where Maturity_Date < '12/31/2017'`? Be sure to [read the help pages](https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow)  and [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of this site to understand how to use it better

Comment: Please provide more information for us to help you. Sample data, formula / business logic etc and expected result will be great

Answer (score 1):

**What i understand from your question is,
you need a date where maturity date less then the 1 year from the as of date...**

```
select * from table_name where convert(date,Maturity_Date)<=convert(date,DATEADD(yy,1,as_of_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you would require something like this:

```
select
    Identiity_Code
,   ID_Number
,   GL_Account_ID
,   As_Of_Date
,   Cur_Book_Bal
,   Maturity_Date
from        [YourTable]
where   DATEDIFF(year,Maturity_Date,As_Of_Date) <= 1
```

Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Hi tried the above and getting %invalid identifier error code in sql devloper

Comment: Please share your full code, then I'll be able to advise